# Define a c++ string as "\"

Tags: c++, string

I need a string that only contains `"\"`. But this doesn't seem to work since (as far as I get it) the compiler sees it as a command instead of a simple string without any meaning.

As you can probably tell, I'm still fairly inexperienced, so aplogies if I'm not that up to speed.

I already tried to use a char, but that also didn't work.

What I want is something like this:
`std::string mystr = "\";`

I get this error message: "A string constant cannot be continued on a second line." Makes sense to me, but doesn't really help me because I'm not even trying to define a string over 2 lines.

Comment: Just use `"\\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
std::string mystr = "\\";
```

Alternatively you can use raw string literals:

```
std::string mystr = R"(\)";
```

Comment: A bit unfortunate that you don't mention raw string literals

Comment: @JVApen great idea, edited that in!